# how to return string value out of for loop scope

Tags: java, selenium

I am facing a issue when fatch the value from xl after that print under the for loop scope then printed. when declare the in return statement and call the method only first cell value print. I want 8 cell value.

```java
public String Sheet_Infor() {

    ReadConfig readconfig = new ReadConfig();   
    String excelPath = readconfig.getExcelPath();       
    int Row =0;
    String s = "";

    try {
        Row = XLUtils.getRowCount(excelPath,"Course 7");

    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (Row = 20; Row<28; Row++) {     
        try {
            s = XLUtils.getCellData(excelPath,"Course 7", Row,1);   
            return s;
        } catch (IOException e) {       
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
            //System.out.println("sss="+s);
    }

    return s;
}
```

Comment: *"I am facing a issue when fatch the value from xl after that print under the for loop scope then printed. "* ... I'm sorry, but it is not clear what you are asking.  Can you try and say it more simply?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  The only code which prints your output is commented out, so naturally it won't print anything.  You're also *returning* inside the `for` loop, so it will only ever return the *first* element from the loop.  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: In this code

when call the method only first cell value print on console
but print this statement under( //System.out.println("sss="+s) Then print right value. can you help me whenever call method then print all 8 value on console.

Answer (score 0):

You can use if(condition) to break/return the required value. For ex, I have a for loop interating upto 10. At value 6 I want to stop and return the value. It can be done as:

```
private test() {
    for (int i = 10; i > 10; i++) {
        if(i==5) {
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want all the 8 cell values then you will have to hold those values in a list/array. You can do it as:

```
public List<String> Sheet_Infor() {
    ReadConfig readconfig = new ReadConfig();
    String excelPath = readconfig.getExcelPath();
    int Row = 0;
    String s = "";
    try {
        Row = XLUtils.getRowCount(excelPath, "Course 7");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Row = 20; Row < 28; Row++) {
        try {
            s = XLUtils.getCellData(excelPath, "Course 7", Row, 1);
            items.add(s);
            return s;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // System.out.println("sss="+s);
    }
    return items;

}
```

Comment: @NirbhaydeepTrigunayat Please dont forget to upvote and accept it, If it resolves your issue :)